# Omnisharp error in C# VSCode "It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs"

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I have a macbook and correctly installed .net and mono.
I am using c# for Unity and I get this error in the OmniSharp Log:

> "[STDERR]   It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
> Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK
> from:
> [https://aka.ms/dotnet-download"](https://aka.ms/dotnet-download%22) Can you please help me fix it?

I tried changing the PATh, installing and uninstalling everything multiple times.

Comment: what SDK did you install - you seemed to have skipped mentioning that

Comment: Take a look [.NET SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download).